# In MVC, Edit function misses the Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have an Edit screen and I am getting an error. The user can edit the object but Foreign Key gets null. And, this causes a huge problem. Why doesnt it get the Foreign Key? here is my code...

First function is perfect, but the one with HttpPost loses TcmbCurrencyId's value, which is a Foreign Key. How can I fix this?

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
    {
        if (Id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        TmcbExchangeRate rate = db.TmcbExchangeRate.Where(x=>x.Id==Id).First();

        if (rate == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(rate);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,TcmbCurrencyId,RateDate,ForexBuying,ForexSelling,BanknoteBuying,BanknoteSelling")] TmcbExchangeRate tmcbExchangeRate)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(tmcbExchangeRate).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(tmcbExchangeRate);
    }
```

Comment: Are you including `TcmbCurrencyId` in the view as an input (hidden or otherwise)? `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TcmbCurrencyId)`? If not then it will not be posted to the controller on submit. Only values used in the form is posted back to the controller on submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are not including the requested property `TcmbCurrencyId` in your form of your view to be posted on submit. If not then it will not be posted to the controller on submit. Only values used in the form are posted to the controller on submit. Given that you haven't included the View in the original post then this is an assumption.

Add this within your form in the View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TcmbCurrencyId)
```